How to change status bar color in iOS Packaged PWA (PWABuilder)
I'm currently developing a Progressive Web App (PWA) that I've packaged as a native iOS app using PWABuilder. While the PWA works perfectly when accessed through a browser and when added to the home screen (status bar color matches the app header as intended), I'm facing an issue with the native iOS version.
Despite setting the background_color and theme_color in the web manifest, which works for the browser version, the status bar defaults to black in the native iOS app, not matching the rest of the app.

Apple Status Bar Style Meta tag is already set:
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

Also, the main primary color is defined in various places:

Background color on  and  tags
theme_color in web manifest
backgrond_color in web manifest

I am testing this on iOS 17.5
